# Connect to VPN within a Windows 10 AWS Workspace

Tags: windows-10, vpn, amazon-web-services

I'm running a Windows 10 AWS Workspace and am wanting to connect to a company VPN from this workspace. I've turned off "Use default gateway on remote network". The Windows VPN interface indicates that I'm connected, but I'm not able to access any network resources like files or web servers.

Unsure what to do next.

Comment: Just to confirm I understand what you are trying to do, you are attempting to connect a AWS Workspace to a company VPN.  Are you sure that the VPN is accessible outside of your company's intranet?

Comment: That's correct. I'm able to connect to the VPN with a non-work machine outside of the intranet.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the AWS instance while your client device is connected to the VPN.  I am going to guess that will fail to work.  This would lead me to believe the problem is the VPN configuration at that point.  The AWS Workspace instance is clearly accessible, since you can connect to it, just not connect it to the VPN.

Comment: I am able to connect to the instance with the client connected to the VPN.

Comment: Notably, when I connect to the VPN from the Workspace with "Use default gateway on remote network" turned on, the Workspace connection drops.

Comment: That sort of points to a VPN configuration issue.